# Need to upload the files to azure using django settings

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

```
`  settings.py
    AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'MY_AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME'
    AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY = 'MY_AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY'
    AZURE_CONTAINER = 'MY_AZURE_CONTAINER'

    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.azure_storage.AzureStorage'

    AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net'
    MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AZURE_CONTAINER}/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL`


view.py

retrieved_image = requests.get(referrence)
image_timestamp = datetime.now().timestamp()
image_name = str(image_timestamp) + '.jpg'
with open(image_name, 'wb') as f:
     f.write(retrieved_image.content)
reopen = open(image_name, 'rb')
django_file = File(reopen)`
```

am getting the file from the locally and pushing that same file to the azure storage. when am trying to do this, it showing **cannot import name 'BlobPermissions' from 'azure.storage.blob'**

Comment: Hi @Mohan T could you please explain more in detail and provide enough code?

Comment: I need to upload the images to the Azure storage using Python Django, and I have mentioned the credentials in the settings.py file. now using of **django_file = File(reopen)** and its showing error

Comment: Can you add the code?

Comment: Hi @Mohan T Could you please edit the question add the code with text and add a few more extra what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Need to upload the files to Azure using django settings

Here, you can follow these steps to upload files from local files to push into Azure blob storage.

**`views.py:`**

```
from azure_blob_project.settings import AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME
from azure_blob_project.settings import AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY
from azure_blob_project.settings import AZURE_CONTAINER
from storages.backends.azure_storage import AzureStorage
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages  # Import the messages module
from .forms import FileUploadForm
import os
from .models import UploadedFile

def upload_to_azure(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            azure_account_name = AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME
            azure_account_key = AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY
            azure_container = AZURE_CONTAINER

           
            azure_storage = AzureStorage(
                account_name=azure_account_name,
                account_key=azure_account_key,
                azure_container=azure_container,
            )

            
            uploaded_file = form.cleaned_data['file']
            file_name = os.path.basename(uploaded_file.name)
            azure_storage.save(file_name, uploaded_file)

            
            uploaded_file_record = UploadedFile(file=uploaded_file)
            uploaded_file_record.save()

           
            messages.success(request, 'File uploaded successfully!')

            return redirect('upload_to_azure')

    else:
        form = FileUploadForm()

    return render(request, 'uploadhtml', {'form': form})
```

**`settings.py`:**

```
AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'venkat678'
AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY = 'xxxxxxx'
AZURE_CONTAINER = 'demo'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.azure_storage.AzureStorage'

AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net'
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AZURE_CONTAINER}/'
```

**`Models.py:`**

```
from django.db import models

class UploadedFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**`forms.py`**

```
from django import forms
from .models import UploadedFile

class FileUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadedFile
        fields = ['file']
```

**`urls.py`**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('azure_blob_app/', include('azure_blob_app.urls')),
]
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Browser:**

[image]

**Portal:**

After uploading in the browser, I checked in the portal it uploaded successfully.

[image]